# Product Cart's database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, architecture, entity-attribute-value

In my project,we have to keep cart information in database.we have 5 products(Product is not going to increase).
Currently we are maintaining just two table(mysql).
Cart_Details(it has cart information) and Product. Product table is common for all the 5 product and data of product is 
kept in json form in a column.

Is it good practice? Should we have separate table for each product and instead of keeping data in json form,  we should have proper columns?
what will be performance trade-off between them.
Currently for complete cart details we query in product table with cart id,just one table is accessed and parse the json data.if we keep separate table
we will have to execute query in all 5 table.

Comment: This question belongs more to the [database admin](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) variant of this platform.

Comment: Don't use JSON unless you have Entity-Attribute-Value.